# How many floating-point operations for Strassen's algorithm for a matrix of size k x k?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multiplication, strassen

I am trying to understand [this analysis of Strassen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Numerical_analysis) for multiply k x k matrices.  But I am still not too sure how many operations are invovled.  Can someone help clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

The number of operations performed is determined as follows.  First, we split the matrix up into four sub strives of size at k/2, and then perform seven recursive multiplications of those matrices.  We then do a constant number of additions of those products to get our desired result.  This gives us a recurrence relation defined as follows:

T(1) = 1

T(k) = 7T(k/2) + ck<sup>2</sup>

Note that lg 7 > 2, since lg 7 > lg 4 = 2. (Here, lg is the binary logarithm).  Thus by case one of the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm is O(k<sup>lg 7</sup>) ≈ O(k<sup>2.807</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given the page says it is approximately O(N^2.807...) I would guess that would be a good approximation of the number of floating-point operations. All the looping/iterating will be with integer operations.